# AJAX - PHP devolver datos con echo me imprime el json en pantalla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Según tengo entendido en una petición AJAX a un archivo php, este devuelve los datos a la petición con echo (comando para mostrar pantalla), pero mi caso es que, al devolver los datos así, esta correcto me los devuelve pero ese echo me muestra el Json en mi pagina web, debajo del DOM modificado.
Aqui el codigo Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    
    listData();

    function listData() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'presentacion/PPaciente.php',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            const pacientes = JSON.parse(data);
            let template = '';
            pacientes.forEach(paciente => {
                tablaPersonas.row.add([paciente.id,paciente.ci,paciente.nombre,paciente.edad])
            });
          }
        });
      }
});
```

PPaciente.php = Codigo PHP:

```
   <?php

    require_once "C:/xampp/htdocs/sistema_dentista/negocio/NPaciente.php";
    
    class PPaciente{
        private $id;
        private $ci;
        private $nombre;
        private $edad;
        private $direccion;
        private $telefono;
        private $NPaciente;
    
        public function __construct(){
            $this->NPaciente = new NPaciente();
        }
    
        public function List(){
            return $this->NPaciente->List();
        }
        
        public function Add($id, $ci, $nombre, $edad, $direccion, $telefono){
            $this->id=$id;
            $this->ci=$ci;
            $this->nombre=$nombre;
            $this->edad=$edad;
            $this->direccion=$direccion;
            $this->telefono=$telefono;
            $this->NPaciente->Add($ci, $nombre, $edad, $direccion, $telefono);
        }
    
    }
    
    $paciente = new PPaciente();
    $pacientes = $paciente->List(); //obtengo un array con los resultados
    echo json_encode($pacientes);  //devuelve los datos a AJAX pero tambien los muestra en pantalla
```

Me devuelve mis datos en respuesta, pero en el formulario después de listarlos en la tabla me lista el json que coloque en el archivo PHP para responder

```
echo json_encode($pacientes);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: crea una nueva función donde agregas datos dummy a la lista `tablaPersonas`
si el problema persiste con `.row.add` descartarás algunos problemas de js

Comment: Asegúrate que no tienes PPaciente.php incluido en indexPacientes.php y que no tienes otro echo en NPaciente.php cuando generas el List().

Answer (score 2):

AJAX te devuelve un string

Para obtener el JSON desde un string puedes usar `JSON.parse`

```js
const miObj = '{"hello":"world","abc":"bcd"}';

console.log(miObj, "esto está en string");
console.log(JSON.parse(miObj), "esto está en JSON");
```

Además, si necesitas convertir un objeto o un array a un string puedes usar `JSON.stringify`

```js
const miObj = {"hello":"world","abc":"bcd"};

console.log(miObj, "Esto está en JSON");
console.log(JSON.stringify(miObj), "Esto está en string");
```

Comment: de hecho si le devuelvo un string a AJAX pero despues utilizo el JSON.parse en mi archivo js.. pero el problema es en el echo de php que no solo devuelve los datos si no muestra ese Json string en la pantalla.